# my own module can not find 2nd class

Tags: python, python-2.7

Hi there i'm working on a project and i'm making it in two files one is to handle all of my functions and one to run and make the GUI. In the py file that i'm importing has two classes so far and i can not use the 2nd class

Example:

```
class one(): #i can use this one
    def __init__(self, var1, var2):
        self.var1 = var1
        self.var2 = var2
    def dosomething(self):
        print self.var1
        print self.var2

class two(): #i can not use this one
    def __init__(self, var3, var4):
        self.var3 = var3
        self.var4 = var4
    def dosomething2(self):
        print self.var3
        print self.var4
```

if i was to add the module to my main file like this.

```
import mymodule

x = "Hello"
y = "World"

z = "Hey"
c = "There"

f = mymodule.one(x, y)
f.dosomething()

s = mymodule.two(x, c)
s.dosomething2()
```

output

```
NameError: name 'two' is not defined
```

If anyone could please help me that would be great i have looked all over this site to find the answer but no luck

Comment: Are you sure class two isn't intended under one?

Comment: try `from mymodule import two`?

Comment: code looks OK, make sure there are no identation or other syntax problems by trying to run the mymodule.py file (will print nothing but will complain if there are errors)

Comment: i tried that and the output was ImportError: cannot import name two

Comment: i get no errors with identation or syntax

Comment: here is a link to download all the files maybe that will help https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzB4Zno1s1KOUFdlX0Z0elJGM0U

Comment: I get no errors with those scripts on python 2.7.13. Output was what I'd expect it to be. Are you sure it isn't some formatting in your actual program? Are you using these exact scripts?

Comment: im using those same scripts with python 2.7.13

Comment: You are not by chance defining `__all__` at the top are you?

Comment: Here is a image to what i am seeing https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzB4Zno1s1KOTWNlZVQ2RXhnZ1k

Comment: i have not added  `__all__ `  to any of my files @hazmat

Comment: Update: i feel so dumb i was looking at my files and seen that i made a copy of my datam.py and it didn't have class two in it and the whole time it was importing that file im so sorry that i over looked that everything works fine now haha.......